# Creating function for laravel controller/view to load database values

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm working on updating a laravel blade template to insert some database info into an html table. IN order to do this, I'm having to add new data to the controller for this blade and that's where I'm having some troubles.

I'm still trying to understand more with laravel, so I'm thinking my syntax or methods of creating this data are incorrect but I just can't put my finger on it right now.

In my function below, the `$calls_allowed` portion was already existing and it works on the page currently. I created the `$contact_events` portion of the function and that's where my problem is.

IN my view, I created a foreach loop and if statement around the html table in question. The table loads, but it's empty even though there are records in the database for the dealer.

I'm trying to say 
`if $dealer-> id matches contact_events.dealer_num, load all records for that dealer`

`contact_events` is the table and `dealer_num` is the column I'm matching, then I'm trying to load the columns from that table (`updated_at`,`method`,`notes`) into the html table.

The affected code is below. The view/route/controller work, it's just this function I'm creating that isn't loading data. Any help is much appreciated.

**Controller code:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $d = Dealer::find($id);
    if(!$d){
        \Session::flash('warning_message', 'Sorry that resource can not be found.');
        return redirect()->route('account.dealer.index');
    }

    $calls_allowed = DB::table('dealers.dealers')->
    where('dealer_num', $id)->
    pluck('calls_allowed');

    $contact_events = DB::table('dealers.contact_events')->
    where('dealer_num', $id)->
    pluck('updated_at', 'method', 'notes');

    if(!empty($calls_allowed)){
        $d->calls_allowed = $calls_allowed[0];
    } else {
        $d->calls_allowed = null;
    }
    return view('Account.Dealer.show')->with('dealer', $d);
}
```

**View code:**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Contacted Date</th>
        <th>Type of Contact</th>
        <th>Call Notes</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach($dealer->contact_events as $events)
    @if($events->dealer_num = $dealer->id)
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$events->updated_at}}</td>
                <td>{{$events->method}}</td>
                <td>{{$events->notes}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    @endif
@endForeach
```

Comment: there is a type here:     @if($events->dealer_num = $dealer->id)   should be ==

Comment: I actually did catch that, unfortunately it still hadn't solved the problem though

Comment: Use dd() to see if $calls_allowed and $contact_events are getting values

Comment: are dealers.dealers and dealers.contact_events  columns on the dealer's table?

Comment: @retrograde dealers is the name of the schema. Contact_events and Dealers are each a table in that schema

Comment: Do you have models set up for those tables?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I added <?php dd($contact_events)?> to the top of the file and it dumped 'null'. It also seemed to do this for $calls_allowed

Comment: @retrograde yes I do, for both tables and several others that are being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not assigning the data to the object after retrieving from database.

```
$contact_events = DB::table('dealers.contact_events')->
where('dealer_num', $id)->
pluck('updated_at', 'method', 'notes');

// add this
$d->contact_events = $contact_events;
```

Comment: Ok, I added that line without modifying anything else and it still isn't loading that data for some reason.

Comment: I added dd($dealer->contact_events) and it does dump one record, but it still doesn't display for some reason in the html table/view

Comment: @TomN.  It might be helpful if you add the dd contents to your answer.

Comment: `pluck` only takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect time to use the power of Laravel's Eloquent ORM...

[Check out the with and has in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

This will require some finessing based on your needs, but it will be something like this:

```
$d = Dealer::where('id', '=', $id)
     ->with('contact_events')->first();
```

This uses Eloquent to get all of the contact_events that belong to the dealer with the $id.

Then you can do something like this
note:  this assumes that calls_allowed is a record on the dealer table. if I misunderstood that, you can still run than you can include that just as you have it.

```
@if(!is_null($dealer->calls_allowed)
@foreach($dealer->contact_events as $events)
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{$events->updated_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$events->method}}</td>
            <td>{{$events->notes}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
@endForeach
@endif
```